# Create labeledPoints from Spark DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

What `.map()` function in python do I use to create a set of `labeledPoints` from a spark dataframe? What is the notation if The label/outcome is not the first column but I can refer to its column name, 'status'?

I create the Python dataframe with this .map() function:

```
def parsePoint(line):
    listmp = list(line.split('\t'))
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(pd.get_dummies(listmp[1:]).sum()).transpose()
    dataframe.insert(0, 'status', dataframe['accepted'])
    if 'NULL' in dataframe.columns:
        dataframe = dataframe.drop('NULL', axis=1)  
    if '' in dataframe.columns:
        dataframe = dataframe.drop('', axis=1)  
    if 'rejected' in dataframe.columns:
        dataframe = dataframe.drop('rejected', axis=1)  
    if 'accepted' in dataframe.columns:
        dataframe = dataframe.drop('accepted', axis=1)  
    return dataframe
```

I convert it to a Spark dataframe after the reduce function has recombined all the Pandas dataframes.

```
parsedData=sqlContext.createDataFrame(parsedData)
```

But now how do I create `labledPoints` from this in Python? I assume it may be another `.map()` function?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you already have numerical features and which require no additional transformations you can use `VectorAssembler` to combine columns containing independent variables:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["your", "independent", "variables"],
    outputCol="features")

transformed = assembler.transform(parsedData)
```

Next you can simply map:

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

(transformed.select(col("outcome_column").alias("label"), col("features"))
  .rdd
  .map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row.label, row.features)))
```

As of Spark 2.0 `ml` and `mllib` API are no longer compatible and the latter one is going towards deprecation and removal. If you still need this you'll have to convert `ml.Vectors` to `mllib.Vectors`.

```
from pyspark.mllib import linalg as mllib_linalg
from pyspark.ml import linalg as ml_linalg

def as_old(v):
    if isinstance(v, ml_linalg.SparseVector):
        return mllib_linalg.SparseVector(v.size, v.indices, v.values)
    if isinstance(v, ml_linalg.DenseVector):
        return mllib_linalg.DenseVector(v.values)
    raise ValueError("Unsupported type {0}".format(type(v)))
```

and map:

```
lambda row: LabeledPoint(row.label, as_old(row.features)))
```