# Create labledpoints from Spark Dataframe & how to pass list of names to VectorAssembler

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I have a further questions from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32557330/5235052
I am trying to build labledPoints from a dataframe, where I have the features and label in columns. The features are all boolean with 1/0.

Here is a sample row from the dataframe:

```py
|             0|       0|        0|            0|       0|            0|     1|        0|     0|           0|       0|       0|       0|           0|        0|         0|      0|            0|       0|           0|          0|         0|         0|              0|        0|        0|        0|         0|          0|    1|    0|    1|    0|    0|       0|           0|    0|     0|     0|     0|         0|         1|
```

```py
#Using the code from above answer, 
#create a list of feature names from the column names of the dataframe
df_columns = []
for  c in df.columns:
    if c == 'is_item_return': continue
    df_columns.append(c)

#using VectorAssembler for transformation, am using only first 4 columns names
assembler = VectorAssembler()
assembler.setInputCols(df_columns[0:5])
assembler.setOutputCol('features')

transformed = assembler.transform(df)

   #mapping also from above link
   from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
   from pyspark.sql.functions import col

new_df = transformed.select(col('is_item_return'), col("features")).map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row.is_item_return, row.features))
```

When I inspect the contents of the RDD, I get the right label, but the feature vector is wrong.

```
(0.0,(5,[],[]))
```

Could someone help me understanding, how to pass the column names of an existing dataframe as feature names to the VectorAssembler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong here. What you get is a string representation of the `SparseVector` which exactly reflects your input:

- you take first five columns (`assembler.setInputCols(df_columns[0:5])`) and the output vector is of length 5
- since first columns of example input don't contain non-zero entries `indices` and `values` arrays are empty

To illustrate this lets use Scala which provides useful `toSparse` / `toDense` methods:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

val v = Vectors.dense(Array(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
v.toSparse.toString
// String = (5,[],[])

v.toSparse.toDense.toString
// String = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
```

So with PySpark:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

df = sc.parallelize([
    tuple([0.0] * 5),
    tuple([1.0] * 5), 
    (1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
    (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
]).toDF()

features = (VectorAssembler(inputCols=df.columns, outputCol="features")
    .transform(df)
    .select("features"))

features.show(4, False)

## +---------------------+
## |features             |
## +---------------------+
## |(5,[],[])            |
## |[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]|
## |[1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0]|
## |(5,[1,3],[1.0,1.0])  |
## +---------------------+
```

It also show that assembler is choosing different representation depending on number of non-zero entries.

```
features.flatMap(lambda x: x).map(type).collect()

## [pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector,
##  pyspark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector,
##  pyspark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector,
##  pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector]
```

Comment: This makes it clear, thanks!. Am new to spark, coming from pandas-scikit, have a follow up question, how do I run linear regression on this rdd? * Do I create a dataframe and then use ML or keep the rdd in this format and use MLLib? * The examples am referring does not help much in understanding the input data structure.[link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#linear-regression) * In pandas, I would split the data into independent x and y, create train, test. fiit the model, test for scores get the coefficients. * How can I do this in spark ML/ MLib?

Comment: update, I could get the lr model running using `from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression`. I can run a small test model, but my code crashes when I scale it up to 56 features, 1.1 million rows. getting an error in this line `distinctValues = df.map(lambda x : x[c]).distinct().collect()` as `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError` I am using Dataproc on Google cloud.

Comment: Mllib regression has been deprecated. Regarding memory issues collecting anything else than small aggregates is doesn't makes sense is generally speaking dangerous. But none of that is really related to this question, is it?